# document.getelementbyid('ID') method is returning null if the element with given ID exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

After lot of R&D i'm writing this query

```
document.getelementbyid('ID').value
```

and

```
$("#ID").val()
```

returning null.

HTML:

```
<div id="visitDate">
    <s:property value="visitDate" />
</div>
<div onclick="GetElement()"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetElement(){
    alert($("#visitDate").val());
}
</script>
```

I see that the value is not being set.

I have tried placing my scripts at the end of my document

It didn't work for me

Comment: put some more code including html code

Comment: you load the html using ajax?

Comment: What element is `#ID`? Most  likely it has not `value` property.

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: Please post your code ?

Comment: <div id="visitDate"><s:property value="visitDate" /> </div>

<div onclick="GetElement()"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function GetElement(){

alert($("#visitDate").val());
}
</script>

Comment: `.getelementbyid` is not the name of a(n inbuilt) javascript function. You need to be using `.getElementById` - capitalization _is_ important!

Comment: @enhzflep Correct, but probably a typo in the post only. If this would had been in the original code, the error message would had occurred: "undefined is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#visitDate').text();
```

Although you'd be better off doing something like:

```
<div id="visitDate"><p>Some Text</p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       var txt = $('#visitDate p').text();
       alert(txt);
    };
</script>
```

Make sure you're linking to your jQuery file too :)

OR

```
function showDivText(){
            divObj = document.getElementById("visitDate");
            if ( divObj ){
                if ( divObj.textContent ){ // FF
                    alert ( divObj.textContent );
                }else{  // IE           
                    alert ( divObj.innerText );  //alert ( divObj.innerHTML );
                } 
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot divObj.textContent is working

Comment: Done :-)

if i want to call onclick method how can i use your 1st method ???

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp